# Can I remove/hide the "Provide a Menu Link" checkbox when creating new content type?

Tags: nodes

I am creating a site where authenticated users (not too computer savvy) will be entering in data to the content types we create and the "Provide a Menu Link" may cause them too much trouble.  Is there a way to remove or hide this option when I create my custom content types?

Comment: Yes by using `hook_form_alter` unset the variable.

Comment: @Sumit, _DO NOT UNSET_ form parts, as that risks seriously breaking things further down the chain, instead set `'#access' => FALSE`.

Comment: @Letharion yeah right I forgot about '#access' key. :(

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 7, go to edit your content type and in the tabs at the bottom there should be 'menu settings'. If none of the checkboxes under 'Available menus' are checked, then the option of creating a menu item is not displayed when creating content of that type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a special role for your non-computer savvy users (go to People menu, then click on Roles tab and add a role). Once you have their role defined, that role will now appear as a long list of checkboxes on the right under the Permissions tab. Scroll down and make sure you uncheck the Menus (Administer menus and menu items) permission. This should prevent them from ever seeing the "Provide a Menu Link" tab when they edit content and/or messing up your menu structure. You can verify this by logging in as that role and then adding/editing content.  This also gives higher-level users with Menu permissions (like yourself) the ability to edit menu preferences and tidy up as needed.

Answer (score -1):

If the users do not have the rights to add new menu items, the option should not be visible to them.

Comment: Sounds to me like he's talking about menu settings when adding content, not adding a menu item.

Comment: Wheter a menu item is added while editing content or in the menu administration dialogs doesn't matter. It's conrolled by the same access rights.

Comment: ahh, true. Your are correct.